# Scraper excel or PDF

Tags: excel, pdf-scraping

I am dealing with a really messy excel data sheet. And I need to clean/re-format it, so it can be feed into ML models. So far, I use time-consuming manual way to flatten the data. I want to do scraper, but don't know if I should export excel sheet to PDF or I should do scraper in excel?
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Save it as CSV or HTML(filtered) and then use a scraping tool  on that. I'd probably just write some VBA to grab whichever parts I wanted from the ragged raw data. YMMV